# Convert SQL to Linq To SQL

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL query that I'd like to convert in to LinqToSql

```
SELECT recWishList.AppId, phyDM.Name,
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, recWishList.Timestamp), 0) AS Date,
COUNT(recWishList.Timestamp) AS Downloads
FROM 
dbo.RecommendWishlist recWishList
INNER JOIN VirtualDevice virDevice
on recWishList.VirtualDeviceId = virDevice.Id
INNER JOIN PhysicalDeviceModel phyDM
on virDevice.PhysicalDeviceModelId = phyDM.Id
GROUP BY 
AppId, phyDM.Name, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, recWishList.Timestamp), 0)
```

The Date column calculation above is a hack that is often used for stripping the time component from a datetime value, essentially setting the time component to zero.

The resultant resultset looks like this:

```
AppId                                   Model           Date                  Downloads
0219d640-6e56-4c09-be8a-a4dc4777bf31    M1           2010-08-30 00:00:00.000 1
04d2de8b-646f-4433-8738-76103344e6b2    M2           2010-12-06 00:00:00.000 1
07d09852e9ca439cb0c573c8292e64f5     M2           2010-08-25 00:00:00.000 1
07d09852e9ca439cb0c573c8292e64f5     M2           2010-09-13 00:00:00.000 1
07d09852e9ca439cb0c573c8292e64f5     M1           2010-08-25 00:00:00.000 2
```

My L2S equivalent is as follows:

```
from app in RecommendWishlists
join virtualDevice in VirtualDevices on app.VirtualDeviceId equals virtualDevice.Id
join physicalDeviceModel in PhysicalDeviceModels on virtualDevice.PhysicalDeviceModelId       equals physicalDeviceModel.Id
group app by new {app.AppId, Model=physicalDeviceModel.Name, Date =    SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(DateTime.Parse("1/1/1753"),app.Timestamp)} into gApp
select new {App = gApp.Key.AppId, Model = gApp.Key.Model, Date = gApp.Key.Date}
```

The resultset look like this:

```
AppId                                   Model           Date                    
0219d640-6e56-4c09-be8a-a4dc4777bf31    M1           94108 
04d2de8b-646f-4433-8738-76103344e6b2    M2           94206
07d09852e9ca439cb0c573c8292e64f5    M2           94103
```

The query works at this point, but I don't have the "COUNT(Timestamp)" column here yet and am trying to figure out how to represent this in LinqToSql. Also, the date is represented as the date boundaries from the DateDiff function and not real datetime values.  Can someone have a look at my L2S translation and see if I am missing anything? Also, how can I get the count of timestamps added to this translation?

============UPDATE==================

From John's guidance below, the final Linq query looks like this:-

```
from recwishlist in RecommendWishlists
join virdevice in VirtualDevices on recwishlist.VirtualDeviceId equals virdevice.Id 
join phydm in PhysicalDeviceModels on virdevice.PhysicalDeviceModelId equals phydm.Id 
group new {recwishlist, phydm} by new {
   recwishlist.AppId,
   phydm.Name, 
   Date =SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value.AddDays(
             SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value,recwishlist.Timestamp))
   } into gApp
   select new {
 gApp.Key.AppId,
 gApp.Key.Name,  
 gApp.Key.Date,
 Downloads = (Int64?)gApp.Count()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to refer to "gApp.Key.Timestamp" instead of "app.Timestamp", since you're selecting from "gApp", and "app" is no longer in context.

**Edit**

So, your current problem is getting the count.  That should be as simple as:

```
select new {App = gApp.Key.AppId, Model = gApp.Key.Model, Date = gApp.Key.Date, Count = gApp.Count() }
```

Comment: but gApp only contains the fields that you specify inside the groupby statement. So are you saying that I would need to calculate the count of timestamps in there and assign it to a field? I thought of doing that, but notice in the original SQL, the count(timestamp) is not in the groupby clause

Comment: Cranialsurge: Yes, just include the missing value in your key if possible.  Otherwise, you'll need to create a dictionary or other value outside of the query, which you can access from inside the select.

Comment: John: Even if i do add the timestamp field in the groupby clause like so - group recWishList by new {app.AppId,phyDM.Name, app.Timestamp} into gApp, i still need a way to do something similar to count(timestamp) the way SQL does it. Right now I can display the timestamps in a column and the query works, but i need to get that count to get the "download" column calculated.